# Programmatically detecting local maximums

Tags: objective-c

My application is collecting about 700 frames of video data from the device's camera. How can I programmatically calculate the frame # of each of the local maximums in my data set, given that all of these values are stored in an array?

I've already thought about simply checking to see if the consecutive values are lower than the value being tested, but this is susceptible to errors if the graph is irregular. I'm searching for noticeable maximums (defined as those you can see with the naked eye that occur about every 10 frames or so.) 
[image]